# Flex: Listening for CollectionEvent in custom component

Tags: apache-flex, e4x, xmllist

(EDIT: I've edited my question to make it simpler,
        sorry if some answers are out of context)

I have prepared a reduced test case for my question:

[image]

I'm trying to create a custom component which is
being fed with XML data coming from the server.
My problem is that the CollectionEvent listener
doesn't get fired and thus labels not updated -

**Games.mxml** (my custom component with listener):

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.*;

        private var _xlist:XMLList;

        [Bindable]
        public function get xlist():XMLList {
            return _xlist;
        }

        public function set xlist(x:XMLList):void {
            _xlist = x;
            trace("set(" + x +")");
            list.dataProvider = x;
            list.dataProvider.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, xlistChanged);                
        }

        private function gameLabel(item:Object):String {
            return "game: " + item.@label;
        }

        private function xlistChanged(event:CollectionEvent):void {
            trace("xlistChanged(" + event +")");
            all.text = "All games: " + _xlist.game.length();
            full.text = "Full games: " + _xlist.game.(user.length() == 3).length();
            vacant.text = "Vacant games: " + _xlist.game.(user.length() < 3).length();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Label id="all" text="All games"/>
<mx:Label id="full" text="Full games"/>
<mx:Label id="vacant" text="Vacant games"/>

<mx:List id="list" labelFunction="gameLabel"/>
```

**MyTest.mxml** (click the buttons to change XML):

```
        private function changeXML1():void {
            games = <games>
                        <game label="1">
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                        </game>
                        <game label="2">
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                        </game>
                        <game label="3">
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                        </game>
                    </games>;                   
        }

        private function changeXML2():void {
            games = <games>
                        <game label="A">
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                        </game>
                        <game label="B">
                            <user/>
                            <user/>
                        </game>
                        <game label="C">
                        </game>
                    </games>;                   
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:XML id="games">
    <games>
        <game label="X">
            <user/>
            <user/>
        </game>
        <game label="Y">
            <user/>
            <user/>
        </game>
    </games>
</mx:XML>

<mx:Button label="Change XML 1" click="changeXML1()"/>
<mx:Button label="Change XML 2" click="changeXML2()"/>
<my:Games xlist="{games.game}"/>
```

Please advise me what is wrong.

Regards, 
Alex

**UPDATE:** edited Games.mxml as suggested by clownbaby - still not working (xlistChanged is never invoked):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
         xmlns:my="*" creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.*;

            private var _xlist:XMLList;

            [Bindable]
            public function get xlist():XMLList {
                return _xlist;
            }

            public function set xlist(x:XMLList):void {
                _xlist = x;
                list.dataProvider = x;
                trace("\n set: " + x);
            }

            private function gameLabel(item:Object):String {
                return "game: " + item.@label;
            }

            private function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
                list.dataProvider.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, xlistChanged);
            }

            private function xlistChanged(event:CollectionEvent):void {
                all.text = "All games: " + xlist.length();
                full.text = "Full games: " + xlist.(user.length() == 3).length();
                vacant.text = "Vacant games: " + xlist.(user.length() < 3).length();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Label id="all" text="All games"/>
    <mx:Label id="full" text="Full games"/>
    <mx:Label id="vacant" text="Vacant games"/>

    <mx:List id="list" labelFunction="gameLabel"/>

</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) The reason your event is not firing is because you are adding the listener after you set `_xlist`.

2) You should not be adding an event listener within your setter anyways.  You should add it on the initialize or creationComplete events of your VBox component.

**EDIT**

Alright, after looking at your code again I can see the problem... so just a few more things.

3) Why are you naming a method `init`, when it gets called on `creationComplete`?  You should get into the habit of naming methods appropriately.  For example, the method that gets called on `creationComplete` should be named: `onCreationComplete`, or `handleCreationComplete`  That way, you will know what your code is doing 6 months down the road.

4) This is your main problem: You are using the getters / setters in appropriately.  If you have a setter, you should also implement a getter (unless you have a write-only field).  More importantly, you should *use* the getter to access your data.  In your `xListChanged` method you are not using the setter you have defined, thus nothing is getting told the `_xlist` actually changed.  As such, you should change your code to:

```
private var _xlist:XMLListCollection;

[Bindable]
public function get xlist():XMLListCollection { return this._xlist; }
public function set xlist(value:XMLListCollection):void
{
    this._xlist = value;
}
```

Whenever you want to access `_xlist`, use the GETTER.  For example, change the dataProvider of your `List` component to be `{xlist}`.  And the `xListChanged` method should be using the getter: `xlist` instead of directly accessing the member `_xlist`.

Comment: I've moved         _xlist.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, xlistChanged); into init(event:FlexEvent) method which I call on creationComplete="init(event)" of the VBox, but this hasn't fixed my both problems. And does it make sense to call addEventListener this early, while _xlist hasn't been set by the setter method?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use GETTER/SETTER as you suggest, because it is XMLListCollection and the custom component gets an XMLList as parameter: <my:Games xlist="{games.game}"/>

I've updated my question with the test code, I'm trying to use list.dataProvider.addEventListener() there... but still no luck.

Comment: I apologize if my edited answer was not clear enough... but you still aren't listening to what I said - which is STOP using `_xlist` in your code, unless you are in a getter / setter.

Update your `xlistChanged` method to use `xlist`.

And please, for the love of god, don't add event listeners in a SETTER.  You are re-adding an event listener every time you set _xlist.  Is that really necessary?

Comment: Thanks I've tried your suggestions - it still doesn't work. Please try MyTest.mxml and the updated Games.mxml and you will see it yourself.

Comment: Okay, good news for you.  I setup your test case this morning and got it working.  If you simply add the `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` event listener to your `List` component (not list.dataProvider), it will fire as expected.  So, in `onCreationComplete()` do, `list.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, xlistChanged);`  Cheers.

Comment: Excellent and thank you for coming back to answer my question. 

Also I've realized, that I can't use a 1-liner like xlist.(user.length() == 3).length() because I have game's without user's too and thus have to check for the cases when user.length()==0. Otherwise I get the error "Variable user not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this:

> public function set xlist(x:XMLList):void {
>
> ```
>    _xlist = new XMLListCollection(x);
>    _all.label = 'All (' + _xlist.length + ')';
>
>    var full:XMLList = _xlist.source.game.(user.length() == 3);
>    _full.label = 'Full (' + full.length() + ')';
>
>    var free:XMLList = _xlist.source.game.(user.length() < 3);
>    _free.label = 'Free (' + free.length() + ')';
> ```
>
> }

You don't need a listener if the only way to set the local _xlist variable is by setting the xlist property.

Comment: Hello John, if I set _full.label and _free.label in the setter method, then they will never get updated again

Comment: They will get updated every time you set the xlist property of the Games component. Which is the only way to change the private _xlist variable anyway.